# How to count unique records through an association using a scope in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I wrote this to count the number of responses (to a post) by unique users:

```
p = Post.find 1
r = p.responses.count(:user_id, distinct: true)
```

I tried translating it to a scope, but it throws an error: `undefined method 'default_scoped?' for 30:Fixnum`

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :post

  scope :by_unique_users, joins(:post).count(:user_id, distinct: true)
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :responses
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :responses
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes:

> All scope methods will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object which will allow for further methods (such as other scopes) to be called on it.

In other words the returned result set needs to be chain-able with other Active Record method calls; calculations aren't chain-able, hence the error you're getting. With that said, if you absolutely want to use a scope we need to make it chain-able:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :unique_responses_for_post, lambda {|post_id| where("post_id = ?", post_id).select(:user_id).uniq }
end
```

You can change the name as needed, I named it according to what it does. With that new scope defined you can do:

```
p = Post.find 1
r = Responses.unique_responses_for_post(p.id).count()
```

---

**Alternatively**

IMO, a more elegant solution for this problem would be to simply define an instance method inside your `Post` model:

```
def distinct_response_count
  responses.count(:user_id, :distinct => true)
end
```

Comment: Interesting article, but I think the jury has yet to be called on that issue.  Scopes are still very popular and IMHO a nicer syntax than methods.

Comment: And the article was updated on 21 Apr 2011, stating specifically that (a) the bug was fixed, and (b) the author uses scopes for easy scopes--so it's down to opinion only for a large number of usecases.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mentioned that the bug was fixed already, but thanks for the comment. I should re-visit this answer at some point and possibly omit the first tidbit of information altogether to avoid confusion.